# Communicating dynamic port numbers

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a Visual Studio solution which consists of five executables, one in c++ and four in c.  They use UDP sockets on local host with fixed ports to communicate with each other.
Now I need to run multiple instances of this program so I believe dynamic ports are required.  How do I arrange it so both sides of a socket know the port number?

Comment: How do you start the applications? If you have one application which startes the other ones, you could pass the ports as arguments.

Comment: One option would be to broadcast a message asking the desired receiver for its current port number, then send your socket data to the reported port as needed. If multiple receivers reply, ask the user which one to use. The receiver will always know the port of the sender so it can send replies back to the correct port.

Comment: @JojOatXGME The main application runs the other four exe files, wonder if I could hold off compiling them until I get the port numbers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Looks like something that should work

Comment: @ChuckD: alternatively, the main app could simply tell the other apps via command-line parameter what specific ports to use. Or, the apps could pick their own ports and then communicate that info back to the main app at startup. Either way, you will need some level of cooperation between your apps to manage the ports dynamically.

Comment: A colleague ended up being assigned this, and had the main app tell the other apps via command line like @RemyLebeau suggested, seems to work ok, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use some other means of communicating the actual port number. For example, save obtain the port number into shared memory or some sort of the file. However, if you are running it locally on the same Windows machine, you might want to use different IPC protocol. For example, Named Pipes.